# Using intl-tel-input on https

Tags: http, ssl, https, ip, intl-tel-input

I am using [intl-tel-input](https://github.com/Bluefieldscom/intl-tel-input) on a production environment. The default requests for the intl-tel-input [ipinfo.io](http://ipinfo.io/) are in HTTPS. This does not happen in my development environment as requests are in HTTP.

Is there any way to override this so that I can use HTTP in production?

My code is:

```
var load_intlTelInput = function(){
    $("#my_phone_number").intlTelInput({
        defaultCountry: "auto"
    });
};
```

PS: There are no intl-tel-input or ipinfo tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of intl-tel-input did not allow for enough customisation in terms of specifying a request and in produciton mode it always defaulted to HTTPS. As we were using ipinfo with a free account. We were in turn blocked form making requests.

I simply updated to the latest version of the software(this is not spam) and specified a custom request. More information can be found on the issues page for intl-tel-input [here](https://github.com/Bluefieldscom/intl-tel-input/issues?q=https%20is%3Aissue).

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the intl-tel-input code at https://github.com/Bluefieldscom/intl-tel-input/blob/42b64c002da735e8c0a90f012083d0d5c67df4c4/examples/js/defaultCountryIp.js the request is always made as a HTTP call, and not a HTTPS call.

If your question is how do you make the call via HTTPS you'll need to modify that code to request https://ipinfo.io instead, or you could change it to call `//ipinfo.io` (no http or https) so that it'll match the protocol of the page it's on (either http or https).

Note that using http://ipinfo.io via HTTPS is limited to paid subscribers, so you'll also need to signup for an access token at https://ipinfo.io/pricing and then add your token to the requests.